# Retrieving an activity-scoped ViewModel in a fragment in onCreateView vs onActivityCreated

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel, android-livedata

Should an activity-scoped ViewModel in a `fragment` be retrieved in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`?

```
viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    viewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<CharSequence>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable CharSequence charSequence) {
            editText.setText(charSequence);
        }
    });
```

I see both examples online. Some say `getActivity()` can return null in `onCreateView`, some say this never happens.

Comment: In my experience I never encountered `NullPointerException` within `onActivityCreated` upon using `getActivity()`. Using `getActivity()` within `onCreateView` seems like a hit or miss.

Answer (score 1):

You should use onViewCreated() instead of onActivityCreated().

onActivityCreated() is called when the activity's onCreate() method returns.
Activity is attached as a host to your fragment in both onCreateView() and onViewCreated() already;

Using onViewCreated() makes more sense to subscribe to data source once the view hierarchy has been created.

Comment: But onActivityCreated is called directly after onCreateView and I think it's safer to call getActivity there than in onCreateView

Comment: yes because your fragments are added inside onCreate() of activity which calls onCreateView() of the corresponding Fragment.

Comment: `yes because your fragments are added inside onCreate()` This is not always true, how about those Fragment that are added later especially when a condition is resolved?

Comment: I get your point. But I think `onActivityCreated` is called every time after `onCreateView`, even if the fragment was just detached or added to the backstack.

Comment: Yes it will be called. In your question, you asked which method would be the best place to create activity scoped viewmodel. I am suggesting that you should create it in onViewCreated() only after your UI has been inflated. Also the data from view model will be bound to the view so it  should be requested in  lifecycle method related to view rather than the fragment.

Comment: But `onActivityCreated` IS part of the Views lifecycle, just as `onViewCreated`. But `onActivityCreated` ha the additional advantage of ensuring that the underlying activity has been created too.